# Flask: flask run not working in conda environment - Windows, Python 3.8 & conda 4.7.12

Tags: python, flask, anaconda

Here is what I did:

1. From start, opened Anaconda prompt
2. Did a `conda create -n flaskEnv pip flask`
3. Did a `conda activate flaskEnv`
4. Did a `cd` to my desired folder
5. Created a file named flaskblog.py with following code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

6. Did a `set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py` and then `set FLASK_ENV=development`
7. Now, I do flask run but it throws an error *Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.*

However, when I add the following code on my file flaskblog.py and then do a `python flaskblog.py`
, it runs fine and serves on my localhost.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am just trying to understand what am I doing wrong when doing a `flask run` from anaconda prompt.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to reproduce, what OS, which python version, conda version? The best practice is to create the environment first, then pip install.

Comment: Windows, its in the heading. Python 3.8 & conda 4.7.12.

Comment: I'm on Windows and followed all your steps and everything ended up working fine. I have a fresh Python 3.8 conda env with flask installed, copied your code, tried to run `flask run` without setting env vars (which failed as expected with the same error you posted), I set both env vars as you described and ran `flask run` again and it worked. Could you check if your env vars get set correctly before `flask run`? (i.e. `echo %FLASK_APP%`)

Comment: @orangeInk, here is a thing I want to understand. Are you using anaconda prompt or windows powershell or command prompt. I too feel, I am missing something very tiny and silly but cant seem to figure out what is the deal. Doing a ```echo %FLASK_APP%``` from my conda environment.

Comment: Update: After I do a ```echo %FLASK_APP%``` I get this ```%FLASK_APP%``` as result. Did a set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py and then set FLASK_ENV=development again and ```flask run``` still throws the same error.

Comment: I use cmder (https://cmder.net/) with command prompt. When `echo %FLASK_APP%` returns `%FLASK_APP%` it means that the env var is not set. Could you try to run `set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py` followed by `echo %FLASK_APP%` and make sure that it prints `flaskblog.py`?

Comment: Exactly, I am a bit late to update on this. Right after I posted my last comment. I created a virtual environment using cmder only. I created a virtual environment with ```virtualenv venv``` command and then created a python flask file. set the environment variable with ```set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py``` and it works fine.

I am not sure why it doesn't work using conda's environment.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and I just closed the terminal and switched everything relating to the project off and then tried again and it worked just fine.